# counting common key-value pairs in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of dictionaries that all share the keys `color` and `object`:

```
inpt = [{'object':'square', 'color':'red', 'size':'big'},
        {'object':'square', 'color':'red', 'coord':(0,0)},
        {'object':'square', 'color':'red'},
        {'object':'triangle', 'color':'blue', 'adj':'beautiful'},
        {'object':'triangle', 'color':'blue', 'attr':'none'}]
```

Here I only care about `object` and `color`. I'd like to count the number of red squares and blue triangles for instance. This means finding the number of times `{'object':'square', 'color':'red'}` and `{'object':'triangle', 'color':'blue'}` occurred. In other words, I need to find the number of commonalities in the key-value pairs in a list of dictionaries like this.

The end result could for example be something like this:

```
{('square', 'red'): 3, ('triangle', 'blue'):2}
```

What is an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), feeding it tuples of the values:

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter((d['object'], d['color']) for d in inpt)
```

This gives you a dictionary subclass with `(object, color)` keys. You could get a list of tuples, in descending count order, using the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
result = result.most_common()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> inpt = [{'object':'square', 'color':'red', 'size':'big'},
...         {'object':'square', 'color':'red', 'coord':(0,0)},
...         {'object':'square', 'color':'red'},
...         {'object':'triangle', 'color':'blue', 'adj':'beautiful'},
...         {'object':'triangle', 'color':'blue', 'attr':'none'}]
>>> Counter((d['object'], d['color']) for d in inpt)
Counter({('square', 'red'): 3, ('triangle', 'blue'): 2})
>>> _.most_common()
[(('square', 'red'), 3), (('triangle', 'blue'), 2)]
```